# Android Support 0 devices SignalR

Tags: android, jar, google-play, signalr, apk

I am having a issue with submitting my app to the google play store because every 
time i upload my APK I get a "Android Supported Devices : 0"

I really have no idea how to fix this. When I remove all references to signalR and remove the jar files, I get 8k devices supported.

Here is some information about my project

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT
Here is Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<!--
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<android:uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
!-->
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/StudyTreeTheme" >
    <activity android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.threedsecure.ThreeDSecureWebViewActivity" />

    <service
        android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService"
        android:exported="false" />

    <!-- Required to use Drop-In -->
    <activity android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.dropin.BraintreePaymentActivity" />

    <!-- Required to use PayPal -->
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalProfileSharingActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.ProfileSharingConsentActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentInfoActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.LoginActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalTouchActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.SignUpActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_profile" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.BaseActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_base" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.CourseListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_course_list" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.TutorLocalSessionActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tutor_profile"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
            android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.StudentProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_student_profile"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
            android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.StudySessionInformationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_study_session" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.dummy.DetailTutorStudySession"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail_tutor_study_session" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.DetailTutorStudySessionActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail_tutor_study_session" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.CreateStudySessionActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_create_study_session" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.TutorStudySessionActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tutor_study_session"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.SessionTimerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_session_timer" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".findTutorActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_find_tutor" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.FindTutorActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_find_tutor" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FindTutorsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_find_tutors" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.StudentRatingActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_student_rating" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.StudentCreditCardActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_student_credit_card"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.TutorPersonalInformationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tutor_personal_information" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
            android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.StudentCreditCardDisplayActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_student_credit_card_display" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ChatActivityPackage.ChatRoomActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_chat_room" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ChatActivityPackage.StudentToTutorChatActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_student_to_tutor_chat" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.TutorProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tutor_profile" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.TutorFeeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tutor_fee" >
     </activity>
     <activity
         android:name=".Activities.ChatActivityPackage.TutorToStudentChatActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tutor_to_student_chat" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.TutorAddRemoveCourseActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tutor_add_remove_course" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ShareWalling"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_share_walling" >
    </activity>
 </application>
 </manifest>
```

Comment: have you followed the solution 2 of my answer.Please post your Manifest file

Comment: Yes, in my question posted above, I am attempting solution 2.

Comment: Johnny, I was able to extract the java files from the jar and add them to the project.  After I did that, the apk showed 8k devices I could support. The problem is that when I went to make a connection using signalR, it throw a run-time error saying "invalid protocol  1.2". I  think I did something wrong when I extracted the java files from the .jar. Do you know who I can add the java files from the .jar file with all the dependencies?

Comment: Tell me one thing first ,have you try removing all signal-r jar files and include all the other dependencies and libraries and then try uploading to store,then how many devices does it supports ?

Comment: Yes, without signalR jar files I get around 8k supported devices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I modified the jar files that were causing the issue. Use this copy if you are having issues with android supporting 0 devices.

https://github.com/eak65/FixedSignalRJar

Comment: Ethan your solution worked for me. Could you please detail the steps you took to modify the jar files as I would like to recreate it in my own environment. it is not always advisable to reference in libraries found on the www!