# SignalR-java client incompatible cpu abi on android kitkat 4.4.2

Tags: signalr, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm able to create signalr using https://github.com/SignalR/java-client.., it works perfect in Android emulator,.. But when I try it on my KitKat tblet 4.4.2 ..I have an error failed CPU abi incompatible ., what I'm missing here??

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Android Support 0 devices SignalR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31282052/android-support-0-devices-signalr?rq=1) save my life,.. Seems the problem is on the pre built jar, u have to modify it..,